# Usercontrol with a list type property is not updating

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have written a VB.NET user control inheriting from a panel which is supposed to contain many buttons. My implementation has the buttons stored as a List(of Button). The bare bones code appears below. When I edit the control at design time, the collection editor opens properly, buttons are also added correctly but they do not appear in the control either at design time or run time. The form designer file shows that they are not added to the Controls collection of the panel. What am I doing wrong?

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections

Public Class ePanel
     Inherits Panel

Private ButtonList As List(Of Button)


<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), Description("Button list")>
Public Property Buttons As List(Of Button)
    Get
        Return (ButtonList)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Button))
        ButtonList.Clear()
        ButtonList = value
        If (ButtonList.Count > 0) Then
            For Each b As Button In ButtonList
                Me.Controls.Add(b)
            Next
        End If
    End Set
End Property



Public Sub New()

    MyBase.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    MyBase.BackColor = Color.Bisque

    If (ButtonList.Count > 0) Then
        For Each b As Button In ButtonList
            b.Dock = DockStyle.Top
            Me.Controls.Add(b)
        Next
    End If

End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: If it inherits from Panel it is not a UserControl.  User controls inherit from UserControl.  You are missing some steps on your collection - first and foremost, it is never instantiated

Comment: It's a Custom Control. You forgot to initialized your `List(Of Button)`. In Sub New() set `ButtonList = New List(Of Button)()`. The `For Each` loop is not useful here because your Custom Control constructor doesn't accept a `List(Of Button)` as a parameter, so your list cannot be filled at this time. You could add a new Constructor: `Public Sub New(ListOfButtons As List(Of Button))` and fill the List there if it's not null. Your base constructor will then be: `Public Sub New() Me.New(Nothing) End Sub`. Your constructor should have a `InitializeComponent()` proc. But you can live without.

Comment: WelcomeOverflow and Jimi 6, you are right, I should have said Customcontrol. I added the line: 'ButtonList = New List(Of Button) ' But the buttons fail to be added from the CollectionEditor to the panel. Which event is fired when I close the CollectionEditor by clicking "Ok"? Thanks

Comment: As I said you are missing several things on your property.  [How to Edit and Persist Collections with CollectionEditor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372/How-to-Edit-and-Persist-Collections-with-Collectio) and a bit newer [Enhanced CollectionEditor Framework](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) the latter has a nice checklist of things which must be implemented

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow Thanks a lot, will go through the links.